# Using Twig to display PHP Object parameters

Tags: php, templates, twig

I am working on moving away from hard coded HTML in my PHP.  I have had some success with basic Twig templates but am struggling with PHP objects.  I have simplified things as much as possible and am still having issues displaying PHP Object parameters.  Hopefully, I am just making a dumb mistake but I have spent a ton of time on this.  If I remove my object and populate an array with data it works fine.

I am reading this in the twig documentation which makes me think it should work:

• check if foo is an array and bar a valid element;

• if not, and if foo is an object, check that bar is a valid property;

**PHP:**

```
<?php
    require_once ('../vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php');

    Twig_Autoloader::register();
    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'test/templates/');$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
        'cache' => './tmp/cache',
    ));
    $template = $twig->loadTemplate('test.phtml');

    $obj = new Person();

    $obj->fName = 'firstName';
    $obj->lName = 'lastName';

    $template->display(array($obj));


    class Person{

        public $fName;
        public $lName;

    }

?>
```

**Template**

```
<html>
    <head><title>Twig template!</title></head>
    <body>

        Person
        <ul>
        {% for person in obj %}
            <li>{{ person.fName }} {{ person.lName }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I do a var_dump I can see my object and the parameters are set.  If I manuualy echo the parameters using

```
echo $obj->fName;
```

it returns the expected value.  The template is showing up in the browser window correctly but the Twig portion is blank.

resulting HTML in browser:

```
<html>
    <head><title>Twig template!</title></head>
    <body>

        Persons
        <ul>
                </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing the `obj` array reference. Try this:

```
$template->display(array('obj' => array($obj)));
```

instead of this:

```
$template->display(array($obj));
```

Hope this help